# Не получается вынести метод из класса в отдельный файл

Tags: c++, компоновщик

Всем доброго!
Вынес реализацию класса в отдельный файл `wall.h`, и пытаюсь вынести методы этого класса в отдельный файл `wall.cpp`.
При попытке запуска программы в VScode я получаю ошибку компоновщика

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  Wall::Wall(double, double), referenced from:
      _main in main-a15ca2.o
  Wall::GetSquare() const, referenced from:
      _main in main-a15ca2.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Если методы описываю внутри класса - все работает.
Уже всю голову сломал, что я делаю не так?
Если в командной строке компилирую - тоже все работает.
`g++ -W --std=c++17 main.cpp wall.cpp -o main`
Какие настройки стоит подправить?

```
//wall.h
class Wall {
public:
    enum class Color {
        BLUE,
        GREEN,
        RED,
        WHITE,
        YELLOW
    };

    Wall(double width, double height);

    double GetHeight() const;
    double GetWidth() const;
    void SetColor(Color color);
    Color GetColor() const;
    double GetSquare() const;

private:
    double width_;
    double height_;
    Color color_;
};
```

```
//wall.cpp
#include "wall.h"
Wall::Wall(double width, double height)
        : width_(width), height_(height), color_(Color::WHITE)
{
}

double Wall::GetHeight() const {
    return height_;
}
double Wall::GetWidth() const {
    return width_;
}
void Wall::SetColor(Color color) {
    color_ = color;
}
Wall::Color Wall::GetColor() const {
    return color_;
}
double Wall::GetSquare() const {
    return width_ * height_;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, просто этот файл забыли подключить для линковки (а может, и компиляции)...

Comment: Когда вы компилируете файл main.cpp, то получаете модуль main.o. Когда вы компилируете файл wall.cpp, то получаете модуль wall.o. Чтобы линкер потом их связал в финальный экзешник без ошибок, ему надо скормить оба этих модуля (плюс все модули подключаемых библиотек). Обычно это происходит автоматически, когда соответствующие cpp-файлы добавляются в проект. У вас, похоже, файл wall.cpp в проект не добавлен.

Comment: @LShadow77 простите уж за такой вопрос, но каким образом мне нужно этот файл добавить в проект? VScode на маке если честно тот еще фрукт. На протяжении всего обучения только и делаю что с бубном танцую. Сейчас попробовал в XCode, все заработало с первого раза. Значит, я полагаю, дело в настройках?

Comment: @Stanislav Polischuk именно! Всё дело в конкретной IDE и её настройках.

Comment: @LShadow77, попробовал в VScode в терминале скомпилировать путем включения всех файлов вручную `g++ -W --std=c++17 main.cpp wall.cpp -o main` и все скомпилировалось, все заработало. Но не могу понять, куда думать, чтобы все работало не из командной строки...

Comment: @Stanislav Polischuk решение одно - гуглить, читать мануал по ide, в которой работаешь.

Comment: @LShadow77, проблему решил))